# Prediction of low class

Tags: r, xgboost, multiclass-classification

I'm training an `XGBoost` on a dataset of 2 millions of rows. But it's too bad to predict classes with low frequency. Is there any parameter on R which can help me to resolve that problem?

Comment: You need to have a balanced data set. Try oversampling or undersampling tehniques

Comment: @AkshayLAradhya I have already done that but the fact is that I have a class of 2% in the dataset. HoW can I handle prediction with this class?